# Delete Descendant in XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml:
 [image: XML FORMAT FILE]

I am currently extracting values from Set node but i get error **Sequence contains no elements** due to the delete set found in the first transaction set.

**Note** i do not want to record null value in case of missing element.

while iterating over all Transactions, I want to delete the full **Transaction** set  where the Delete element is present.

Snippet of my code :

```
 foreach (var trans in xDocument.Descendants("Transaction"))
 {
     //Table Item
     var val1 =(string)trans.Descendants("Set").Elements("szItemID").First();                                
     var val2 =(string)trans.Descendants("Set").Elements("lMerchandiseStructureID").First();
     var val3 = (string)trans.Descendants("Set").Elements("szItemTaxGroupID").First();

    dataToBeWritten.Append(val1);
    dataToBeWritten.Append(",");

    dataToBeWritten.Append(val2);
    dataToBeWritten.Append(",");

    dataToBeWritten.Append(val3);
    dataToBeWritten.Append(",");

    dataToBeWritten.Append(Environment.NewLine);

}

Console.WriteLine(dataToBeWritten.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Please post the XML as *text* in the question - along with a [mcve] rather than just a snippet. (And please format the code so it's indented cleanly.)

Comment: When deleting from a list() object always go from end to beginning otherwise you skip items and get the error you are seeing.  Try : for(int i = xDocument.Descendants("Transaction") - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var trans = xDocument.Descendants("Transaction").Skip(i).FirstOrDefault();
}

Comment: @jdweng , i cannot adopt this way since the transaction set with the delete tag appears in the file occasionally. I believe i will always be skipping the first transaction set this way. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I had similar project in college 40 years ago.  The teacher had file with user inputs that contained errors.  The final program was 500 punch cards and I threw 1000 punch cards into the circular basket.  Lesson was to check for invalid input data.  Lesson learned, If you have a list 1,2,3,4,5 and remove 3 then 4 will be skipped if you go forward.So you will move through the list 1,2,3 (delete), 5. You will skip 4.With my method you will move through the list 5,4,3 (delete),2,1.But in this case to must follow input in order.When you get an error you can either report and quit or continue.

Comment: @jdweng Right now when ever i am getting this error it goes in the catch section and the application stops. This is causing lot of inconvenience because the files are not being converted, i had to intervene to remove that transaction tag.. I am not checking for null because the application that will process my output file cannot accept null record

Comment: Add the exception handler inside the for loop so you can continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do the for each on Insert element instead?

```
foreach (var trans in xDocument.Descendants("Insert"))
```

This will ignore Delete node.

========================================

Ok. Adding a new answer. You need to check if Set.Count()==0, if its 0, just continue the loop.

```
    foreach (var trans in xDoc.Descendants("Transaction"))
    {
        //Table Item
        var itemSet = trans.Descendants("Set");
        if(itemSet.Count()==0) continue;

        var val1 =(string)trans.Descendants("Set").Elements("szItemID").First();                                
        Console.WriteLine(val1);
    }
```

Comment: i cannot loop through insert since , i am taking a record as per transaction set, in one transaction i can have several insert set

Comment: Added a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the transactions with a Delete child just just do something like this `xDocument.Descendants("Transaction").Where(e=>e.Element("Delete")!=null).Remove()`.
But to prevent the exception you could just use `FirstOrDefault()` and test for `null` or even better, since you need only the fisrt element just use `Element()` instead of `Elements().First()`

Comment: I tried it out, and the full error message is: A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.. Any idea? I am not checking for null because the application that will process my output file cannot accept null record

Comment: Well it means that there's already a variable called e, just change the name of the variable in the lambda. I think that you should check for null anyway to prevent exceptions, maybe just skip a cycle with continue in case of a null value